# Scala: how to let the compiler infer the type from a function argument of type Seq[T]?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I'm making a generic function which sorts different subclasses of the following class:

```
class SortableByGeographicPoint(val geographicPoint: Int)
```

Its subclasses look like this one:

```
case class A(id: Int, override val geographicPoint: Int) extends SortableByGeographicPoint(geographicPoint)
```

My function is:

```
def sortByGeoPoint[T <: SortableByGeographicPoint](sequence: Seq[SortableByGeographicPoint]): Seq[T] = {
   sequence.sortBy(_.geographicPoint) map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

It is not so bad but **I have to specify the type T when I want to use it, and I'm looking for a solution to avoid this**.

I would like to do something like this:

```
def sortByGeoPoint(sequence: Seq[T <: SortableByGeographicPoint]): Seq[T] = {
   sequence.sortBy(_.geographicPoint) map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

Is it possible to do this, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `asInstanceOf`, which is unsafe:

```
def sortByGeoPoint3[T <: SortableByGeographicPoint](sequence: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = 
  sequence.sortBy(_.geographicPoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `T` in the `Seq` type parameter?

```
def sortByGeoPoint[T <: SortableByGeographicPoint](sequence: Seq[T]): Seq[T] =
  sequence.sortBy(_.geographicPoint)
```

Here `T` is a subtype of that class and you can access the `geographicPoint` parameter without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I just have to do this:

```
  def sortByGeoPoint2[T <: SortableByGeographicPoint](sequence: Seq[SortableByGeographicPoint]): Seq[T] = {
      sequence.sortBy(_.geographicPoint) map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
  }
```

and I can call my function without giving the type like this:

```
sortByGeoPoint2(Seq(A(1, 2)))
```